# Memory-efficient way of computing the median of a large data set?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, complexity-theory, median, memory-efficient

If one computer can only hold 1 million numbers, how to find out the median number from 100 million numbers?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311764/is-it-possible-to-calculate-median-of-a-list-of-numbers-better-than-on-log-n

Comment: At best, this should probably be Community Wiki.

Comment: This is a valid programming related question, how to compute the median in a memory efficient way. It just comes along as a puzzle.

Comment: Use the "Median of medians" approach.

Answer (score 3):

#### Do an *[external sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting)* and then scan once for the median.

Hopefully, the real problem was "how do I do an external sort"? (If this is homework...I want to help in the right way. :-)

Comment: This is what I thought. :) But I'm not sure it's the correct answer, so I asked here.

Comment: There has got to be a way to do this with the literal constraint that the device can only store 1 million numbers. Using the external sort seems like cheating. Now I'm gonna be up all night thinking about this.

Comment: Heh, I wondered that myself. It's a really good question.

Answer (score 3):

Reduce the problem to a more difficult one: sort the 100 million numbers
using [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Merge_sorting_tape_drives)
Then, take the 50 millionth element.

Comment: But the computer can hold 1 million numbers only, how can I find the 50 millionth one?

Comment: On the tape (oh, right, this is no longer the 80s. I meant "on the disk"), at the 50 millionth position. You have storage for your 100M elements, right? Because if you don't (elements read from a stream) the exercice can be proved impossible by a counting argument.

Comment: It is not correct for 100 million numbers to take 50 millionth element, because 100 million is even number, so one has to take mean of 50 millionth and 50 millionth + 1 elements

Answer (score 1):

Using 101 computers and a sort-merge just like a database.

Comment: Lol. This answer should feature as the best programmer joke!

Comment: I'll take it as one of my answers.:)

Answer (score 0):

Find the middle million numbers and then report the median of them.  (Hmmm, now how to find those middle million numbers...)